# Incorrect decrement of reference count for retained property

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I guess I still don't understand this yet. I'm not using ARC on this project.

For a propert, `aProperty` declared with the retain attribute, I would expect that the assigned object is retained twice in the following statement:

```
self.aProperty = [UIView alloc] init...];
```

Once from the alloc, and once by the setter.

So I release the object once immediately, like this:

```
self.aProperty = [UIView alloc] init...];
[self.aProperty release];
```

The compiler gives an error message:

> Incorrect decrement of reference count of an object that is not owned at this point 
>   by the caller.

Is the retain count incremented by the setter, making it two, at that point?

Also, what does "not owned at the point by the caller" mean? This could be a problem that I'm not familiar with.

Comment: possible duplicate of [why \[self.property release\] will cause the static analyzer to show an "incorrect decrement of the reference count" error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005751/why-self-property-release-will-cause-the-static-analyzer-to-show-an-incorrect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify what is happening.

```
self.myVar = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

is equivalent to calling

```
[self setMyVar:[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame]];
```

When using a `@property` with retain it's implementation would end up looking something like this (this is just a rough example)

```
- (void)setMyVar:(UIView *)myVar;
{
    if (_myVar != myVar) {
        [_myVar release];
        _myVar = [myVar retain];
    }
}
```

So now we can say that

```
+----------- +1 retain ------------+
|                                  |
[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame]
```

and

```
+------ +1 retain ----+
|                     |
_myVar = [myVar retain];
```

which is +2 for the count. We then would have something like

```
- (void)dealloc;
{
    [_myVar release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

which is -1, which just leaves us with a memory leak as there is stil +1 retain.

The pattern I favour is

```
UIView *myVar = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
self.myVar = myVar;
[myVar release]; myVar = nil;
```

so that memory is released as soon as possible and no dangling pointers are left as it is `nil`'led out

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it warns you because the object isn't declared as a simple variable but as owned by somethings else (in this case, `self`) and wants to prevent you from randomly releasing objects.

Try either this:

```
UIView *view [UIView alloc] init...];
self.aProperty = view;
[view release];
```

Or this, what I typically do:

```
self.aProperty = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Comment: I did this instead: [dataToBeLoaded_ release]; The error message went away. This makes it looks as if you should not release the property. I still need verification from someone that it has been retained twice and needs a release. (I avoid autorelease, when I can, to keep the pool as small as possible.)

Comment: `autorelease` works perfectly well, really. I did not notice any bad effect on performance, even when using it many, many times. Maybe the compiler even optimizes that code to work without `autorelease`?

Comment: The object indeed gets `retain`ed twice and therefore needs a `release`. To deallocate the object, send it a second release message (you probably do this in the object's own `-dealloc`)

Comment: The `init` method inherited from `NSObject` does nothing; it's actually `alloc` that sets the initial retain count. You might want to edit your answer.